# How to try out OpenStack on 4 servers instead of 7?

Tags: openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

We have a "test bed system" of 4 servers only (not 7).

How do we get this to work with
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack using only 4 servers?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with the currently released Autopilot.  If you select Ceph for both object and block storage then 4 machines should be sufficient.  Be aware that you'll need at least one machine with two NICs for the network gateway in your cloud (one NIC on the same Network as the other machines as the cloud, and one for external access).

You'll also need to limit the overhead of MAAS and Landscape to one machine, for example:

1. Install MAAS on a machine
2. Install Landscape in a VM on the MAAS machine
3. Register the MAAS server in Landscape
4. Navigate to Landscape's OpenStack tab and follow the instructions

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I manually installed most of the services for OpenStack on a single node using the syntax:

```
juju deploy --to lxc:0 *servername*
```

...in most cases.  This will create LXC containers on that first node.  So basically, you end up putting all these services on the first node [noting the machine number in square brackets]:

1. juju-gui                 [0/lxc/0]
2. mysql                    [0/lxc/1]
3. keystone                 [0/lxc/2]
4. glance                   [0/lxc/3]
5. cinder                   [0/lxc/4]
6. nova-cloud-controller    [0/lxc/5]
7. openstack-dashboard      [0/lxc/6]

And then deploy three ceph nodes:

```
juju deploy -n 3 ceph    [1], [2], [3]
```

And a ceph-osd node:

```
juju deploy ceph-osd     [4]
```

And the first compute node:

```
juju deploy nova-compute [5]
```

So that's six computers (nodes) so far.  You can always "juju add-unit nova-compute" later to add another node to the compute list.

You'd actually like to include three of the ceph-osd nodes, to be honest.  It helps make that work better for the sake of redundancy.  Take note of the configuration variables that set the minimum quorum size to match your node count.

Of course, this is a simplified syntax above since in some cases you reference a configuration file.  And then you'd want to run the series of "juju add-relation x y" commands to bind together pairs of services.  Having the juju-gui up first allows you to visually see what's going on.

IMPORTANT!  Cinder seriously DOES NOT WORK in Icehouse if you use a block-device that's defined locally (if you're trying to omit ceph, for example).  Every time I tried this cinder failed with a hook error at the config-changed step.  It can't create that local block device and fails.  Trust me, I've spent weeks trying this without ceph and it simply doesn't work.  Ceph requires a quorum of three nodes minimum so you're stuck with a minimum install I've described.  You might be able to deploy ceph-osd to lxc:0 again on that first node but I couldn't tell you if that will work--I'm still struggling with re-commissioning some of my nodes at this point and dealing with the bootstrap-timeout errors.